# Outlook truncating images

Tags: image, email, templates, outlook, truncate

I'm designing an e-mail template for a company and it tests great in everything besides Outlook. For some reason the bottom images of the email look like they're loading half way and then stop. I've found information online that Outlook won't load images with a height greater than 1728px, but the tallest image we have is much shorter than that. There are images beyond 1728px on the page that are loading just fine, so I'm not sure that's the issue. Does anyone have any experience with this? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: This is an old question, but I wondered if you've found a solution? We notice the same behavior, but some (identical!) mail load correctly, others don't, and the ones that are loaded half are not the same ones for all users.

Comment: I believe I discovered that the 1728px rule is for each root table in the template. So if you have an email template that is over 1728px, you'll have to find a spot in there to end the first table and start a new one. If you have to use more than two tables then you're working with so much information that you should probably split it up into different emails all together. I used Litmus.com to do a lot of my email testing and highly recommend it. Email On Acid also looked like a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Here is a quick solution for this to be done in the outlook.

Use photoshop and follow this steps:

1. Once the design is over, slice up the image parts / height(1728px as per yout example).
2. Save this as, File->Save for web and device. click save. you will get option under save box
3. Under format change this to HTML and image from drop down.
4. Save them in one folder. A new HTML file and image file will be created in this folder.
5. Open this HTML file in a browser.
6. Just copy and paste the content in the outlook using a single cell table.
7. That's you are done. Now your image will load without any problem.